# What kind of error is it considered when a person uses the wrong form of a word?

Tags: orthography

I guess I asked the question in the title. Basically, when it comes to using the wrong form of a word (*to* instead of *too, there* instead of *they're,* etc.), what kind of error is this considered? Grammar, spelling, syntax, semantic, orthographic.

Thanks! 
Brian

Comment: Spellling. If you're dealing with writing, it's a spelling problem. Or error. Most people don't care how they're spelled; since it doesn't make any difference in speech, it must not be anything important, or we wouldn't understand speech. And of course we do, much more easily than writing.

Comment: Don't you get annoyed by people who can't differentiate between *you're* vs *your*, *their* vs *there* vs *they're* ! ! !  It's called teenage lackadaisical English. AKA mid-life-crisis-with-teenage-delusion English.

Comment: Bicycles cannot stand up by there selves because they are two-tired.

Comment: Also note that sometimes it's impossible to tell whether they *just mistyped it* (a typographical error) or *didn't know how to spell it* (an orthographic error) or knew how to spell the word they used, but didn't know the word they used was not the right one. (a syntactic or semantic error). And in this day and age there is also the helpful "*auto-correct*" error.

Comment: I won all the spelling bees in grade school but my spelling has detereated from frequent visits to internet forums.

Comment: @TRomano, I see wut yoo did their.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your examples describe spelling errors, to which the linguistic technical term *orthographic* can be applied.

[**orthography**

*n, pl* -phies

     1. (Linguistics) a writing system

     2. (Linguistics)

          a. spelling considered to be correct

          b. the principles underlying spelling

     3. (Linguistics) the study of spelling](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/orthography)

--Collins English Dictionary

Linguists, at least generally, do not use *form* to describe the different words you provided. They are just that: different *words* or, more technically, *lexemes* which are also *homonyms.*

[**word form** - the phonological or orthographic sound or appearance of a word that can be used to describe or identify something; "the inflected forms of a word can be represented by a stem and a list of inflections to be attached"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/word+form)

--WordNet 3.0, Farlex clipart collection.

Different forms of a word include such examples as *dog* and *dogs* or eat and ate. In these sense that child and children are the same word, they are the same *lexeme.* *Dog* and *dogs* are two forms of one lexeme, as are *eat* and *ate.*

Note: The fundamental answer here comes from John Lawler's comment to the question.

Comment: This is the answer that I was just about to write. +1

Comment: Here's a diagram of how _Lexeme_ works, as one of [the three meanings of "word"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/threekindsofword.pdf).

Comment: So the *lay* bone's connected to the (bap!) *lie* bone?